# JSON and SQLite

Tags: android, json, sqlite, save

I store my information(my app inform...) with help JSON. All is ok, but is one nuance.
When i clear the RAM, all information is removed. I know that it is clearing temporal information. Tell me way how can to get around this. I looked to the side Clouds and BACKEND but i need well information, to begin to understand this technology.
If you can give some URL with good instructions, publications or some books about Clouds or BACKEND.
And another how to be when device hasn't internet connection?

Comment: You don't mention Sqlite at all in your post. JSON isn't Sqlite. If you want a simple cloud backend, Parse.com is a good option

Comment: where i sad that JSOI is SQLite??????????

Comment: You didn't, but your question is titled JSON and Sqlite. I don't know where JSON has any part of your question unless you are just dumping JSON strings into Sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to use [external storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).

Comment: Can you give information about Clouds?\The Best Clouds?